# k out of n probability

Tags: probability, statistics, reliability

An engineering system consisting of n components is said to be a k-out-of-n system (k≤n) when the system functions if and only if at least k out of the n components function. Suppose that all components function independently of each other and are not identical.
If the ith component functions with probability pi, i=1,2,3,4, compute the probability that a 2-out-of-4 system functions.

Option 1:
$$ \Bbb ℙ(2,3,4)  $$

$$=P_1 [1−(1−P_2)(1−P_3)(1−P_4)]+ $$
$$P_2 [1−(1−P_1)(1−P_3)(1−P_4)]+ $$
$$P_3 [1−(1−P_1)(1−P_2)(1−P_4)]+ $$
$$P_4 [1−(1−P_1)(1−P_2)(1−P_3)] $$

Option 2:

Would it be the same as 4-choose-2?
$$ \Bbb ℙ(2,3,4)  $$
$$ \Bbb =P_1 P_2 P_3 P_4 $$
$$ - P_1P_2 
 - P_1P_3 
 - P_1P_4 
 - P_2P_3 
 - P_2P_4 
 - P_3P_4 
 - P_1P_2P_3P_4
$$

Comment: What's the question? Are you looking for confirmation of your answer, or for a simpler form, or to understand the given answer?

Comment: i dont think my answer is right.   looking for the answer for, 2-out-of-4 components functioning for the entire system to be functioning.

Answer (score 1):

Almost ... no where near what you need..

$$\quad{p_1\big(1-(1-p_2)(1-p_3)(1-p_4)\big)}\\ + {p_2\big(1-(1-p_1)(1-p_3)(1-p_4)\big)}\\ + {p_3\big(1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_4)\big)}\\ + {p_4\big(1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)\big)}$$

What you have is the probability that the first component functions and not all three of the others fail, or the second does and not all three of the others do, or... so forth.   On closer inspection, those are not disjoint events.

---

You require the probability that two, three, or four components function.   I suggest using the **principle of inclusion and exclusion**.

> $${p_1p_2+p_1p_3+p_1p_4+p_2p_3+p_2p_4+p_3p_4}\\{-p_1p_2p_3-p_1p_2p_4-p_1p_3p_4-p_2p_3p_4}\\{+p_1p_2p_3p_4}$$

Comment: thx for the input Graham.  so what you added at the end is the part for adding in probabilities that the components fail?  confused.

Comment: the case where Prob (success) for each of the 4 components are  identical and independent is the binomial case, so that's easy enough but when its independent and NOT identical is more complicated and that's the case i am after here.

Comment: Are you saying that's the 4-choose-2 case?   i'll take a gander.

Comment: i dont understand your example Graham.

Comment: I remember using a graphical example with circles grayed out or leaved empty when I was in undergraduate, maybe that would help him understand ?

Comment: Right Marine, i think that graphical example depicts how one needs to remove the double counting.. am i right?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with.  But I am unable to come up with the generalized equation, so there may be some errors in here.

$$ P_1P_2P_3P_4  $$
$$ +(1-P_1)P_2P_3P_4  $$
$$ +P_1(1-P_2)P_3P_4  $$
$$ +P_1P_2(1-P_3)P_4  $$
$$ +P_1P_2P_3(1-P_4)  $$
$$ +(1-P_1)(1-P_2)P_3P_4  $$
$$ +(1-P_1)(1-P_2)(1-P_3)P_4  $$
$$ +(1-P_1)(1-P_2)(1-P_3)(1-P_4)  $$
$$ +P_1(1-P_2)(1-P_3)P_4  $$
$$ +P_1(1-P_2)(1-P_3)(1-P_4)  $$
$$ +P_1P_2(1-P_3)(1-P_4)  $$

Comment: Yes? No?  Maybe?  heck No?

Answer (score 0):

The system functions when **2 or more than 2** components work. Thus it should be $\binom{4}{2}+ \binom{4}{3}+ \binom{4}{4} $ combination of individual component probabilities. Thus  $E $ is the event when system functions,
$$
\begin {align*}
P(E) = & p_1 p_2(1-p_3)(1-p_4)+ p_1 p_3(1-p_2)(1-p_4)+ p_1 p_4(1-p_2)(1-p_3)\\
+& p_2 p_3(1-p_2)(1-p_1)+ p_2 p_4(1-p_1)(1-p_3)+ p_3 p_4(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\\
 +& p_1 p_2 p_3 (1-p_4)+ p_1 p_3 p_4(1-p_2)+ p_1 p_2 p_4(1-p_3)+ p_2 p_3 p_4(1-p_1)\\
+& p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4
\end {align*}
$$